# Transitiveness of set sizes

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Given that:
$$|A|\le|B|<|C|$$
Prove that:
$$|A|<|C|$$

---

I proved that:
$$|A|\le|C|$$
By showing a $1:1$ function from $A$ to $C$, in the following way:
$$\exists f:A\to B, \exists g:B\to C$$
$f$ and $g$ are $1:1$,
So their composition, $g \circ f$ is $1:1$ too.

Now I need to show that no onto function exists from $A$ to $C$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $f:A\to C$ is a surjection and let $g:A\to B$ be an injection. $g$ has a partial inverse $g^{-1}:g(A)\to A$ and then $f\circ g^{-1}:g(A)\to C$ is onto. If we arbitrarily extend $f\circ g^{-1}$ to $B$, then we get a surjection from $B$ onto $C$, contradiction.